# riddle with keys

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

**Part 1**
I have keys, but I don’t open any locks. I have a ribbon, but I didn’t win, place or show. I need some help from nature to be useful.

**Part 2**
Now what is special about this word? Hint:

> Tell me again about the fox and the dog.

Comment: I've edited the post, to correct grammar and remove inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 22):

I think you are a

> Typewriter

I have keys, but I don’t open any locks.

> The typewriter has keys for typing letters

I got a ribbon but I didn’t win, place or show.

> A typewriter has an ink ribbon for transferring pigment to paper

I need some help from nature to be useful

> Pieces of paper, made from trees and usually called "leaves", so could be a play on words.

Part 2

> It's usually said that *typewriter* the longest word which you can type only using the top row of letters.

Hint

> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is a sentence that uses all the letters of the alphabet and can be used to check a typewriter is functioning correctly.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was thinking. Tiny nitpick:  jumpS, not jumpED